# How can I change a local variable to an instance variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

So I am completely new to this.
I am following a local weather tutorial

http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/09/03/adding-local-weather-conditions-to-your-app-part-12-implementing-corelocation/

Its not working as it should.  When I hit RUN, a window pops up saying do you want to allow this app to access location manager.  But the message disappears before I have a chance to hit it, then the app does nothing.

Below is my code... upon researching I found this info

While difficult to track down, the solution for this is quite simple.

Through much trial and error I found out that while the location access dialog pops up when you try to access any location services in the app for the first time, the dialog disappears on its own (without any user interaction) if the `CLLocationManager` object is released before the user responds to the dialog.

I was creating a `CLLocationManager` instance in my `viewDidLoad` method. Since this was a local instance to the method, the instance was released by `ARC` after the method completed executing. As soon as the instance was released, the dialog disappeared. The solution was rather simple. Change the `CLLocationManager` instance from being a method-level variable to be a class-level instance variable. Now the `CLLocationManager` instance is only released once the class is unloaded.

This might be the answer but I dont know how to change from method level to class level varable.

Can someone please assist in changing this to a class level variable?

here is my code

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@protocol LocationGetterDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) newPhysicalLocation:(CLLocation *)location;
@end

@interface LocationGetter : NSObject
<CLLocationManagerDelegate>{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    id delegate;
}

-(void)startUpdates;

@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id delegate;

@end


    #import "LocationGetter.h"
    #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@implementation LocationGetter

@synthesize locationManager,delegate;
BOOL didUpdate = NO;

- (void) startUpdates{
    NSLog(@"Starting Location Updates");

    if (locationManager == nil)
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Your location could not be determined." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}

// Delegate method from the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol.
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manage didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    if (didUpdate)
        return;

    didUpdate = YES;
    // Disable future updates to save power.
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    // let our delegate know we're done
    [delegate newPhysicalLocation:newLocation];
}

@end



    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "LocationGetter.h"

@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder
    <UIApplicationDelegate, LocationGetterDelegate>
{
    UIWindow *window;
    ViewController *viewController;
    CLLocation *lastKnownLocation;

}

@property (retain, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (retain, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocation *lastKnownLocation;

@end




    #import "AppDelegate.h"
    #import "ViewController.h"
    #import "LocationGetter.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize lastKnownLocation;
@synthesize viewController;
@synthesize window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
//    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
//    // Override point for customization after application launch.
//    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
//    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
//    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    spinner.center = CGPointMake(self.viewController.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.viewController.view.frame.size.height / 2);
    [spinner startAnimating];

    [viewController.view addSubview:spinner];

    // get our physical location
    LocationGetter *locationGetter = [[LocationGetter alloc] init];
    locationGetter.delegate = self;
    [locationGetter startUpdates];

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];



    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

- (void)newPhysicalLocation:(CLLocation *)location {

    // Store for later use
    self.lastKnownLocation = location;

    // Remove spinner from view
    for (UIView *v in [self.viewController.view subviews])
    {
        if ([v class] == [UIActivityIndicatorView class])
        {
            [v removeFromSuperview];
            break;
        }
    }

    // Alert user
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location Found" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Found physical location.  %f %f", self.lastKnownLocation.coordinate.latitude, self.lastKnownLocation.coordinate.longitude] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you need to fix up. First off, your `locationManager` is already an instance variable. There is nothing to change there. But you declare `locationManager` property but never use it. Get rid of the property or actually use it. If you keep the property, it doesn't need to be public since no outside class is using it.

Also, your `delegate` property is defined incorrectly.

The real problem you are experiencing is due to your app delegate implementation. You create a local instance of `LocationGetter` and then let it go out of scope at the end of the method. You need to add a `LocationGetter` instance variable to your app delegate. This will allow the instance to stay alive longer than just the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

Here's how I would update the code (assuming ARC is enabled):

LocationGetter.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@protocol LocationGetterDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) newPhysicalLocation:(CLLocation *)location;
@end

@interface LocationGetter : NSObject

-(void)startUpdates;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<LocationGetterDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

LocationGetter.m:

```
#import "LocationGetter.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface LocationGetter () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end

@implementation LocationGetter {
    BOOL didUpdate = NO;
}

- (void) startUpdates{
    NSLog(@"Starting Location Updates");

    if (self.locationManager == nil)
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Your location could not be determined." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}

// Delegate method from the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol.
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    if (didUpdate)
        return;

    didUpdate = YES;
    // Disable future updates to save power.
    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];

    // let our delegate know we're done
    [self.delegate newPhysicalLocation:newLocation];
}

@end
```

AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *lastKnownLocation;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "LocationGetter.h"

@interface AppDelegate () <LocationGetterDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) LocationGetter *locationGetter;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
//    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
//    // Override point for customization after application launch.
//    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
//    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
//    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    spinner.center = CGPointMake(self.viewController.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.viewController.view.frame.size.height / 2);
    [spinner startAnimating];

    [viewController.view addSubview:spinner];

    // get our physical location
    self.locationGetter = [[LocationGetter alloc] init];
    self.locationGetter.delegate = self;
    [self.locationGetter startUpdates];

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: going in order... locationManager is already an instance variable.  Since I am not using it which area do I delete it from?   and then how do I add an instance of LocationGetter to appdelegate?

Comment: See my updated answer with code. I typed this all in quickly, there may be mistakes.

Comment: okay, thank you!! It is working now.  I really need to understand what I am doing.  Now that you know the concepts I am working on, can you recommend the proper subjects so I can research them in detail.  Hopefully explaining why and where I put all the code where I did to make it work.  I know one subject I need to read up on is delegation.

Comment: Go to the Apple iOS Developer page (where you download Xcode) and look at all the links. Find info on the basics of Objective-C. Don't skip the basics of the language.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean change it to be an *instance variable* not a *class variable* (Objective-C doesn't have such a concept).  Well, you already did that.  Anything that lives in here:

```
@interface Foo : SuperFoo
{
    //...
}
```

Or here:

```
@implementation Foo
{
    //...
}
```

is an instance variable.

Comment: in the post i found.. it said ARC was releasing my instance variable of location manager, do you think this is true?

Comment: Yes it is true, but it is not "early".  ARC released it right where it should.  When a strong variable goes out of scope and has no more strong references, it will be deallocated.

Comment: so I guess I'm trying to figure out why the popup window that says, ALLOW TO ... is disappearing on me.  Any idea?  Do you think its because I have location manager in a instance and it shouldnt be?

Comment: I don't know, I am just answering your question about how to make an instance variable.  Are you saying that it still disappears now?